# How to add event to OK button in `this.$bvModal.msgBoxConfirm(...)`?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-vue

I have a bootstrap-vue project.
I follow this [tutorial](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal#message-box-advanced-usage):

I can use confirm modal to open a big image modal.

```
      showBigImg(src, id) {
        const h = this.$createElement

        const BigImgVNode = h(
          'div',
          {class: ['foobar']},
          [
            h('b-img', {
              props: {
                src: src,
                fluid: true,
                center: true
              }
            })
          ]
        )

        this.$bvModal.msgBoxConfirm([BigImgVNode], {
          buttonSize: 'sm',
          centered: true,
          size: 'lg',
          okTitle: 'OK', 

        }).then(value => {

        })

      }
    }
```

but I have a question, I search [official docs](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal#message-box-advanced-usage) many times, I don't get the way to add an event to ok button.

I also tried:

```
        this.$bvModal.msgBoxConfirm([BigImgVNode], {
          buttonSize: 'sm',
          centered: true,
          size: 'lg',
          okTitle: 'OK', 
          ok: ()=> {
            console.log("ok button clicked.")
          }
        }).then(value => {

        })
```

but not work, please tell me how to add the event to OK button in `this.$bvModal.msgBoxConfirm(...)`  this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the following paragraph from the docs. You can use the return value from the Promise to determine how the modal was closed. Where the returned value will be `true` if the `OK` button was pressed.

> Both methods return a Promise which resolve into a value when the modal hides. `.msgBoxConfirm()` resolves to either `true` (OK button pressed), `false` (CANCEL button pressed), or `null` (if the modal was closed via backdrop click, Esc press, or some other means.
>
> https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal#modal-message-boxes
> (Quote found a slightly under the table in linked section)

```js
async showModal() {
  try {
    const result = await this.$bvModal.msgBoxConfirm(
      "Click the `OK` button to see an alert.",
      {
        title: "Confirmation Box"
      }
    );

    if (result === true) 
      alert("OK button was pressed");
    else if (result === false) 
      alert("CANCEL button was pressed");
    else if (result === null)
      alert("The modal was closed by the user using other means. (ESC, Backdrop, ect..)");
  } catch {
    alert("The modal was destroyed before the user could make a decision");
  }
}
```

##### Working Example

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    async showModal() {
      try {
        const result = await this.$bvModal.msgBoxConfirm(
          "This is a confirmation box", {
            title: "Confirmation Box"
          }
        );

        if (result === true)
          alert("OK button was pressed");
        else if (result === false)
          alert("CANCEL button was pressed");
        else if (result === null)
          alert("The modal was closed by the user using other means. (ESC, Backdrop, ect..)");
      } catch {
        alert("The modal was destroyed before the user could make a decision");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-btn @click="showModal">
    Show Modal
  </b-btn>
</div>
```